# NSButton not responding to performSelector:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

So I have a button that is attached to an action called writeToFile:

The action opens an NSPanel and allows the user to enter the name of the file they want to write to their desktop.

The problem I am having is I can't update the user and let them know that the write was successful before the NSPanel closes.

So I put a label or NSTextField because I am talking about a mac app inside the NSPanel and the NSTextField updates and tells the user that the write was a success.

I change the button title that is attached to the action writeToFile: to "close" and I am trying to change the method the button actually calls by using performSelector:

However, I keep getting an "Unrecognized selector"

Here is some code, any and all help is greatly appreciated:

```
- (void) closePanel {
       [theSheet close];
}

- (IBAction) writeToFile: (id)sender
{

    if ([_nameOfFile.stringValue length] > 0) {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:_nameOfFile.stringValue];
        NSString *string = _inputTextView.string;
        BOOL OK = [string writeToFile:path
                       atomically:YES
                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:NULL];

        if (OK) {

            _statusField.stringValue = @"File written to desktop";
            _writeButton.title = @"close";
            [_writeButton performSelector:@selector(closePanel)];

        } else {

            _statusField.stringValue = @"Sorry, something went wrong :(";

        }

    } else {

        _statusField.stringValue = @"Please name the file first!";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
[_writeButton performSelector:@selector(closePanel)];
```

for:

```
[_writeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(closePanel)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I am actually writing a Mac app so the above code wouldn't work as NSButton doesn't perform the addTarget: action

Comment: I figured it out... 

I just needed to change the above code to: 

[_writeButton setAction: @selector(closePanel)]; 

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

That's because `_writeButton` doesn't implement `-closePanel`. Your class does. Change it to:

```
[ self closePanel ];
```

Comment: But now I can't see the NSTextfield update because the NSPanel closes so quickly...

Comment: In that case, you'd want something like `[ self performSelector: @selector(closePanel) afterDelay: 0.50f ];`, which will invoke the `-closePanel` method after half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the delegate?

```
[_writeButton setTarget:self];
[_writeButton setAction:@selector(writeToFile:)];
```